# is php json_encode & AJAX breaking my array?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I'm grabbing some database entries, creating a 2D array and then passing them to js with AJAX. But when I loop through the array in javascript, it's an "undefined" mess. The console log for **dbArray** works fine, so I know the PHP/AJAX is working. Not sure what I am doing wrong with the loop...

PHP ('load-words.php):

```
$query = mysql_query("
SELECT * FROM words 
ORDER BY RAND() 
LIMIT 50
") or die(mysql_error()); 

$dbArray = array(); 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $word_phrase = stripslashes($row['word_phrase']);
    $description = stripslashes($row['description']);
    // construct a 2D array containing each word and description
    $dbArray[] = array($word_phrase,$description);      
};

echo json_encode($dbArray);
```

Javascript:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'func/load-words.php',
    success: function(dbArray) {
        console.log(dbArray);
        var items = "<ul>";
        for (var i in dbArray) {
            items += "<li><a href='#'><b>" + dbArray[i][0] + ' : ' + dbArray[i][1] + "</a></li>";
        }
        items += "</ul>";
        div = $('#dbArray');
        div.html(items);
    }
});
```

Comment: What is the output of "console.log(dbArray);"?

Comment: for arrays, you should be using `for (i = 0; i < dbArray.length; i++) { ... }`. the `var i in` version is for iterating object properties.

Comment: The OP called it an array, but really it IS an object as it's coming in as JSON, so the for-in is fine.

Comment: but doesn't JSON encode make it an object?

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [*red box*](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: @Eugene the output of console.log(dbArray); is my data exactly as I want it (a 2D array). It's when it goes through the loop that things go wrong...

Comment: @matski I do beleive you :) But I't hard to tell what's wrong with the loop without seeing the actual data.

Comment: @Eugene Heh, I understand. Actually Utkanos has solved it below. I just needed to declare the datatype in the AJAX call. I *knew* my loop was OK!!

Comment: @Utkanos: Not necessarily.  `json_encode` can make arrays too.  `'[{"a":12}, {"a":13}]'` is valid JSON.

Comment: @rdlowrey I know about this, but haven't gotten around to it yet. This isn't a live project yet. Thanks for the links, I will read up :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess this is failing because jQuery is interpreting the AJAX response as a string, since your PHP is not outputting a JSON header and your AJAX is not stipulating JSON. This is easily tested:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'func/load-words.php',
    success: function(dbArray) { alert(typeof dbArray); /* "string"? */ }
});
```

Try

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'func/load-words.php',
    dataType: 'json', //<-- now we explicitly expect JSON
    success: function(dbArray) { alert(typeof dbArray); /* "object"? */ }
});
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks so much. That's a good lesson to learn, next time I'll know!